# Deduplicate and reorder dictionary

Tags: python, django

Let's say we have a basic model.

```
class Log(models.Model):
    key = fields.BigInteger()
    calldate = fields.DateTimeField()
    followupdate = fields.DateTimeField()
```

There can be multiple followupdates set for the same key. What I would like to do is present the most recently (by calldate) scheduled followup in the list.

In my view, I have the following:

`# views.py`

```
def callbacks(request):
    """ get objects where a followupdate has been specified """
    q = Log.objects.filter(followupdate__isnull = False).order_by("-calldate")

    """ deduplicate key so only most recently scheduled followupdate show """ 
    newresults = []
    seen_key = []   
    for result in q:
        if result.key not in seen_key:
            seen_key.append(result.key)
            newresults.append(result)

    results = newresults
    """ What I want to do is equivalent to results.order_by("followupdate") """
    """ But since it's a dictionary now and not a queryset, I can't """
    return render_to_response('callbacks.html', {"callbacks":results})
```

What I need help with is reordering the dictionary, `results`, by the key `followupdate`. In each dictionary there is a key like this: `'followupdate': datetime.date(2013, 3, 25)` this is what I need to reorder by.

Comment: A dict is unordered in Python. What you can do is to create a list of `(key, value)`, which will be ordered.

Comment: Are ordering and sorting different concepts in python? If they are, perhaps I'm really just looking to "sort".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.sort()` seems to work like this -

```
l.sort(key=lambda item:item['followupdate'], reverse=True)
```

Test cases -

```
>>> l = [{'followupdate': datetime.date(2013, 3, 25)}, {'followupdate': datetime.date(2013, 3, 24)}, {'followupdate': datetime.date(2013, 3, 29)}]
>>> l
[{'followupdate': datetime.date(2013, 3, 25)}, {'followupdate': datetime.date(2013, 3, 24)}, {'followupdate': datetime.date(2013, 3, 29)}]
>>> l.sort(key=lambda item:item['followupdate'], reverse=True)
>>> l
[{'followupdate': datetime.date(2013, 3, 29)}, {'followupdate': datetime.date(2013, 3, 25)}, {'followupdate': datetime.date(2013, 3, 24)}]
```

Comment: This worked as expected, but I had to change it a bit. `sort(key=lambda x: x.followupdate, reverse=True)`

Comment: Ah yes. I assumed it to be dictionary. Should be an object.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the database to do the de-duplication, instead of fetching records from the database only to discard them in Python, which is a waste of time and bandwidth.

Django's object-relationship mapping isn't up to this, but you can do it in SQL like this:

```
SELECT L1.*
FROM myapp_log AS L1,
     (SELECT MAX(date) AS maxdate, `key`
      FROM myapp_log GROUP BY `key`) as L2
WHERE L1.date = L2.maxdate
  AND L1.`key` = L2.`key`
  AND L1.followupdate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY L1.date DESCENDING
```

(The field name `key` needs to be quoted since it's a SQL keyword.)

You can then run this query from Django using the [`raw()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw), like this:

```py
sql = '''
    SELECT L1.* FROM myapp_log AS L1,
    # and so on (see above)
    '''
q = Log.objects.raw(sql)
```

Comment: I'd also recommend this approach. Much more efficient.

Comment: I would like to use this, but I'm a bit too unfamiliar with SQL to be writing raw statements. Appreciate the response tho +1

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I'd suggest you start making your hand dirty with SQL. ORM spoils one.

Comment: The only SQL I (believe) I'll ever use is enough to pull an entire table into Python or R where real magic happens. Not sure it's worth it! That's exactly why I chose Django, because it allows me to avoid mucking with things I don't know!